# Delete Contact-Data in Highrise API

Tags: api, highrise

How do you delete contact-data from a person via the Highrise API? Its clear how to add contact data, or delete a person, but how do you delete an email address, postal address, or phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when you PUT the record you just include a dash/negative in front of the id for the email, address, or phone-number element.